# How to correctly implement in a new function the scoping behavior of Table, Sum and other commands that use Block to localize iterators?

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, scoping, syntax-highlighting

It is documented that "Block is automatically used to localize values of iterators in iteration constructs such as Do, Sum, and Table." Therefore the dummy index (iterator) in a Sum is shielded against a global variable with the same name, for example:

```
k = 123;
Sum[f[k] + f[k], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

gives the result:

```
Sum[2*f[k], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I am creating my own version of the Sum command, this is the way I thought Block[] had to be used:

```
SetAttributes[mySum, HoldAll];
mySum[arg_, {index_Symbol, limits___}] :=
  Block[{index, evaluatedarg},
   Print["debug msg 1"];
   evaluatedarg = arg;
   With[{replaceevaluated = evaluatedarg},
            mySum[replaceevaluated, {index, limits}] /;
     HoldComplete[replaceevaluated] =!= HoldComplete[arg]] 
   ];
```

However the "index" variable inside Block[] becomes red, Mathematica showing a scoping conflict that I do not see. Now, it gives the correct result, but the problem is that the function gets called several times (instead of only two times, as I was expecting), as in this sample run:

```
k = 8;
mySum[f[k] + f[k], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

which gives the output:

```
debug msg 1
debug msg 1
debug msg 1
debug msg 1
debug msg 1
debug msg 1
mySum[2 f[k], {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

It is bad that the function gets called so many times, because when it is part of a large expression, with nested sums and other algebraic manipulations, the calculation becomes too slow to be useful. It seems this behavior is because of the scoping problem in the index variable, because if I rename the index inside Block to index2 (which of course destroys the scoping I wanted) and run in a fresh Mathematica session, the message is only printed twice (the first time when the rule is really applied, and the second time when it is determined that the rule does not apply for the new mySum). So my questions are a)How does the scoping problem make the function to be called more than twice?, but more important for me b)What is the correct way to implement the "Block" behavior in the command mySum so it works like the standard Sum command?

Comment: The Perhaps some context could be helpful. Why do you need to re-implement `Sum`? Would it be possible to use e.g. upvalues instead, to "overload" the behavior of the built in function and deal with your objects?

Comment: @MarcoB The context is that I am the main author of an old Mathematica package for Quantum Mechanics http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/jose.luis.gomez/quantum/ and I am creating the new version, but from scratch, from zero. I need a new Sum that must work in operators and kets, where the multiplication is noncommutative. I did this already in the old package, but it was inefficient and ugly, this time I want to do it right

Comment: You are using `Condition` a.k.a. `/;` in the last step, but there is no pattern to the left of your `/;`. What is this supposed to do here?

Comment: I tried `mSum[body_, {index_Symbol, limits__}] /; 
  Block[{index}, HoldForm[body] =!= body] := 
 Block[{index}, mSum[Evaluate[body], {index, limits}]]`, but this gives me recursion and iteration limit errors. A `Trace` reveals that at the second recursion of `mSum[f[k]+f[k],{k,-Infinity,Infinity}]`, MMA evaluates `{2 f[k] =!= 2 f[k], True}` which I cannot understand

Comment: You can safely ignore the warning and red highlighting. It simply tells you that the variable will be injected into  `Block` by the top-level rule (your function), rather than being the actual symbol. In most cases, things like that happen due to a programmer's  mistake, which is why there is a warning. But in your case, you do want to use `Block` exactly like that. Also, while there is a warning, in the case of `Block` the outer `SetDelayed` won't attempt to rename variables, since `Block` is a dynamic rather than lexical scoping construct - so you don't have to worry about that either.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, as you probabily have seen already, the way I am using Condition is documented in the "Details" section of the help of the commands With and Block, it allows to share the result of a calculation (in my case "evaluatedarg") with local variables (in my case "index") between the pattern matching and the body of the function, similar to the use of Condition in the help page of  Message http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html?q=Message, an important part of the calculation is done before pattern matching. And I believe your Trace actually shows my real problem

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I also believed I could ignore the red warning, and implemented several different rules for mySum using this construct, but the calculations became very slow. I discovered that each rule was used many more times than what I was expecting, so I did reduce it to the somehow minimun example I am posting. If I change index to index2 inside Block (which of course totally destroys the scoping I wanted) and evaluate in a fresh kernel, the matching is attempted only two times, not six times. Any suggestions to have both the scoping and the matching used only 2 times in this example?

Comment: @MaTECmatica What I can tell after having a brief look: you could reduce the number of calls in half, if you'd use `mySum[arg_, {index_Symbol, limits___}] /; ! ValueQ[evaluatedarg] :=...` instead of `mySum[arg_, {index_Symbol, limits___}] `. I don't see how you can further reduce the call number, off hand - but it might be possible, of course.

Comment: @Leonid Are you going to Answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, I put my comments as an answer, as requested.

Comment: Dear @Leonid, combining your answer with using HoldAllComplete instead of HoldAll, I was able to get only one function call. I decided to post it as a second answer, since it can be very useful for future users, and I believe it is more visible as a second answer than just as a comment. Regards!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can safely ignore the warning and red highlighting. It simply tells you that the variable will be injected into `Block` by the top-level rule (your function), rather than being the actual symbol originally present in `Block`'s declaration list. Which is exactly what you want here.

In most cases, things like that happen due to a programmer's mistake, which is why there is a warning. But in your case, you do want to use `Block` exactly like that. Also, while there is a warning, in the case of `Block` the outer `SetDelayed` won't attempt to rename variables, since `Block` is a dynamic rather than lexical scoping construct - so you don't have to worry about that either.

As to the number of calls, one thing you can do to reduce them is to replace

```
mySum[arg_, {index_Symbol, limits___}] := ...
```

with

```
mySum[arg_, {index_Symbol, limits___}] /; ! ValueQ[evaluatedarg] := ...
```

This would cut the number of calls in half, for your example.

Comment: Dear Leonid, combining your answer with using HoldAllComplete instead of HoldAll, I was able to get only one function call. I decided to post it as a second answer, since it can be very useful for future users, and I believe it is more visible as a second answer than just as a comment. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

After one week of constant trial and error, I discovered that I only have to use the attribute HoldAllComplete instead of HoldAll:

```
SetAttributes[mySum, HoldAllComplete];
mySum[arg_, {index_Symbol, limits___}] := 
  Block[{index, evaluatedarg}, Print["debug msg 1"];
   evaluatedarg = arg;
   With[{replaceevaluated = evaluatedarg}, 
    mySum[replaceevaluated, {index, limits}] /; 
     HoldComplete[replaceevaluated] =!= HoldComplete[arg]]];
```

It gives the desired behavior, if we execute:

```
k = 8;
mySum[f[k] + f[k], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

we obtain:

```
debug msg 1
debug msg 1
mySum[2 f[k], {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

that is the correct answer with only two function calls. Even better, if we combine with the answer of Leonid, replacing:

```
mySum[arg_, {index_Symbol, limits___}] /; Not[ValueQ[evaluatedarg]] := ...
```

then we obtain the correct answer with a single function call. Exactly what I need.

Comment: That's great. Indeed, `HoldAllComplete` was the missing piece. Somehow I overlooked this. +1.